# Would a hosted ZooKeeper service be useful? Is there one?

Tags: hosting, apache-zookeeper

I think ZooKeeper is great.

However, you would ideally need 3-5 servers in different data centres to really get a reliable service. That implies provisioning, setup, configuration and in many use cases, the app or service (e.g. Kafka) is not even going to write/read a lot from ZooKeeper. ZooKeeper just has to ... be there. So the cost of hosting could be shared between many different companies. (With the proper security features in place of course).

I'm thinking about making such a small service that does this for people. But would anyone be interested? It would be free for small use cases, e.g. 3 nodes with less 1,000 writes per month.

Comment: Did you find such a service? or, did you create one?

Comment: No didn't find a service. Also it didn't seem like there was a lot of interest for such a service. Maybe ZooKeeper is just used internally and people are happy to run the service themselves? Are you interested?

Comment: I'm just starting to learn about ZooKeeper, and don't really want to set up 3 servers to experiment with! At least it's relatively easy to spin up Docker instances.